# K unit in Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hnoB.png)

I writing some text for school and i need to know what unit is this? Kilobit or KiloByte? 
Thanks for answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K is short for Kilobyte (KB).

> The binary representation of 1024 bytes typically uses the symbol KB,
>   with an uppercase letter K. The B is often omitted in informal use.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Answer (score 0):

The digits are limited to be a 0 or 1 and each digit is called a bit or (binary digit) and you can grouped them together either 4 bits (nibble) or 8 bits (byte).
bit (01)  \Binary digit
nibble(0101)
A byte is made of eight bits example: (01010101)
so Kilobit is one thousand bits and kilobyte is compose of one thousand bytes.

Comment: I am not sure how the answer is related to "know what unit is this? Kilobit or KiloByte?" -1 :)